# Git construct a specific commit shat which looks good in example for educational purposes

Tags: git

For training purposes I would like to create a Git repository with some easy-to-read commit sha values. Example:

```
* 2222222 second commit on main branch
| * bbbbbbb commit on branch B
|/  
*   1111111 first commit in repository
```

I know that each SHA is a unique combination of the sha for the blobs, the filenames (tree) and the commit message including author name/email. To make things reproducible, we will not sign commits (since this will also include the sign key and commit time in the commit sha)

Given I can vary the commit message, my question is:

**For any given tree-blob combination, how to I create a commit message with a specific commit SHA?**

My limits and assumptions:

- I can vary the commit message
- I am interested only in the first 7 characters of the SHA (not the full 40 characters)
- I am OK with a brute-force approach to make my small commit examples pretty to look at

Also, my definition of "pretty" may vary, but at least something like `1111111`, `1111aaa`, `abc1234`, and even `fa1afe1` (the coolest example used in some git manual pages)

Comment: You can't change the hash output for a commit without hacking into the SHA-1 algorithm AFAIK.  But...why do you have this requirement?  Just show the first say 7 characters as the major repositories do.

Comment: Personally I think trying to make it pretty is a less ideal way to teach `git`. You want the users to understand that the commit hashes are unique and determine at time, and doesn't follow a specific style. That is you can't set it. Teach them to have meaningful commit messages other than "update". I would just commit as is. Illustration with trees help understand branching.

Answer (score 2):

If you restrict yourself to a small prefix of the hash, then you can indeed do this.  Git does this in a variety of places in its testsuite for testing its handling of colliding short names.

Because SHA-1 is designed to be indistinguishable from random, however, the effort to create 7 hex digits with a particular value is 2^28 for each commit.  Doing this for the full hash would be computationally infeasible.

In order to do this, you should create some example content, fix the author and committer names and timestamps using the `GIT_AUTHOR_*` and `GIT_COMMITTER_*` environment variables, and then repeatedly attempt to create a commit by changing the commit message (e.g., with an incrementing number).

You will likely be better off writing a script to compute the commit repeatedly without spawning Git itself, since that will be much faster, so you'll need to synthesize the tree by using `git write-tree` with the contents of the index and then synthesize the rest of the commit with fixed values in your script.  You can use `git cat-file commit HEAD` to see what a commit looks like.

Comment: bk2204 this is definitely the direction to go. However, I will keep the question open to other answers since I would also like to encourage working code exmaples

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [Preimage Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) on SHA1. According to the Wikipedia page it has not been performed successfully on full SHA1.

TL;DR it's not worth it.